# FFMPEG add audio track while converting video formats

Tags: audio, video, ffmpeg, video-conversion

**Background**

I need to convert AVI files to H264 (MP4). I am successfully doing so with the following:

```
-i mymovie.avi -c:v libx264 -crf 19 -preset slow -c:a libfaac -pix_fmt yuv420p -f mp4 -b:a 192k -y -an output.mp4
```

I am calling the command via a C# .Net Winforms applications, although I suspect this will have little impact on the answer.

**The Question**

How do I add an audio track? I need to add one, as I need to be able to upload the videos to Instagram, which it seems rejects files without an audio track (to my annoyance). In reality I do not need an audio track that is very long. My thoughts were a couple of seconds of "silence" in MP3 format.

I think I will need AAC audio as the output.

For the record I also realise the `-an` command will provide no audio and I have taken this away in my later attempts.

**Attempts so far**

I have gathered I will need to use the `-shortest` command as the audio will be shorter than the video. In reality I will be adding a blank MP3 (or similar) just so while encoding I get an audio stream embedded in the video.

I also have tried using the `-map` command but without success.

Answer (score 1):

Ok here is the command I have working. I discovered I did not have `libfaac` in my build of ffmpeg so i switched. I did not need the `-map` options either as FFMPEG can deal with 2 inputs fine without extra config.

```
-i test.avi -i music.mp3 -c:v libx264 -crf 19 -preset slow -c:a libvo_aacenc -pix_fmt yuv420p -f mp4 -b:a 192k -y -shortest output.mp4
```

The differences between my original  and what works are:

- libvo_aacenc replaces `libfaac`
- `-shortest` is added to deal with shorter audio than video
- `-i` is used to provide the audio input

**Update**

The command after some great input in the comments is now

```
-i test.avi -i music.mp3 -c:v libx264 -crf 19 -preset slow -c:a aac -strict experimental -pix_fmt yuv420p -f mp4 -b:a 192k -y -shortest output.mp4
```

Comment: Note that of all the AAC encoders you can use with ffmpeg, libvo_aacenc offers the worst quality. Better to use `-c:a aac -strict experimental` and a bitrate of over 96k. This is the ffmpeg-internal encoder.

Comment: How do I add the bitrate or will it take it from the source file? Thanks for improving my answer! Have I done anything else wrong?

Comment: `-b:a` sets the audio bitrate, so in your example you'd only need to change the encoder part. Some minor things: the `-y` option should go before the inputs, and `-f mp4` is not needed. Apart from that it looks good to me!

Comment: Also see the [FFmpeg and AAC Encoding Guide](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/AACEncodingGuide).

Answer (score 1):

You can generate a silent audio stream with the [`aevalsrc` audio source](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#aevalsrc):

```
ffmpeg -y -i test.avi -f lavfi -i aevalsrc=0 -c:v libx264 -crf 19 -preset slow \
-pix_fmt yuv420p -shortest output.mp4
```

This is easier than using a blank audio file as an input.

Comment: How does the -shortest command work with this setup?

Comment: @GrahamSmith Apparently it does nothing in this case. I assumed your video has a finite duration and that `aevalsrc` will generate silence indefinitely, so I added `-shortest` to make sure the output ends at the end of the video, but it appears that the output will end with the video anyway.

Comment: Awesome input and great follow up. Thought my comment maybe of use to others reading this. Thanks again.